# REST API notebook like ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, rest-client

Currently i am using postman rest client for checking API syntax for various products.

Is there any tool available like ipython notebook for testing REST API.

IPython notebook is a server which we can run python programs and store the programs and its outputs as a notebook. We can later open those notebooks and can view all the programs which we did.

I would like to store the API testing details with response and want to share those things.

Using postman, i can create a collection and share and i hope i cannot save the responses. Here in ipython notebook, i can save both the input and output.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use python library to do your rest testing, or if you really want something more custom, I would suggest looking at writing a [wrapper kernel](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/development/wrapperkernels.html) or even maybe a full kernel for IPython. It allows to use your own custom languages in cells. See the [a few of the existing kernels](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages). 
And don't be afraid to try to write one, it's quite easy,